# AppDomain Creation In .Net

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, appdomain

Is there a way we can clone Current Application Domain & its Assembly in to new created domain to execute same piece of code in multiple domain having same dependencies as current domain have.

Answer (score 1):

No.

But you could write a method that creates an ApplicationDomain and loads specific assemblies into it.

Comment: Well that sucks.  To take advantage of dynamic compilation, for example to translate C# source code friendly type names into actual .NET Type instances, we have to load dynamic assemblies into a separate domain so they can be unloaded (otherwise I'd be generating a new assembly in memory for every type I want to translate).  But the compiler is having trouble, because it can't find assemblies.  It would be so much easier if we could just clone the current AppDomain.  The setup is otherwise very convoluted, with PrivateBinPaths, LoaderOptimization, ApplicationBase, Assemblies vs Modules, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It is very well possible to create an assembly and hook up assemblies to it and run it. I use a library called [NSandbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nsandbox/) to ease the creation of app domains while running unit / integration tests ([read introduction here](http://thevalerios.net/matt/2008/10/nsandbox-an-introduction/)).